# Formatting Date in Knockout Template

Tags: javascript, knockout.js, knockout-2.0

I'm wanting to format a date in knockout's template. 
The date is currently being returned as

```
2013-07-04T00:00:00
```

I would like it to be displayed like

```
07/04/2013
```

Here is the binding I'm using

```
<td data-bind="text: FirstDate">
```

Are their default formatting properties in Knockout's template?

Comment: There is nothing built in Knockout regarding date formatting or formatting in general. You need to use a thrid party library like [moment.js](http://momentjs.com/) for this.

Comment: Thanks @nemesv I included moment.js. <td data-bind="text: moment(FirstDate).format('L')">. Does exactly what I wanted.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

There is nothing built in regarding date formatting or formatting in general in Knockout. The `text` binding just converts the property value to string so if you want custom formatting you need to do it yourself.

Working with dates is not so easy in JavaScript so you are probably better with using a third party library like [moment.js](http://momentjs.com/) for this. It is very simple to use and it can format your dates with the [`format` method](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/displaying/format/). There is built in format `'L'` for your required Month numeral, day of month, year formatting.

You can use moment js in your view-model or directly in your binding like:

```
<td data-bind="text: moment(FirstDate).format('L')">
```

Or you can create a custom binding handler which encapsulates this formatting logic.

Note: Make sure to use `()` on your `FirstDate` property if it is an `ko.observable` inside your data-binding expression to get its value.

Comment: @lola the available format options are listed in the moment.js documentation: http://momentjs.com/docs/#/displaying/format/

Answer (score 2):

I use moment.js in a modified version of [Stephen Redd's date extender](http://www.reddnet.net/knockout-js-extender-for-dates-in-iso-8601-format/).
It looks like this, which is a little cleaner than calling a function in a data bind.

```
<input type="text" data-bind="value: dateOfBirth.formattedDate" />
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also use MomentJs to create an extender:

```
ko.extenders.date = function (target, format) {
    return ko.computed({
        read: function () {
            var value = target();
            if (typeof value === "string") {
                value = new Date(value);
            }

            return moment(value).format("LL");
        },
        write: target
    });
}
```

viewmodel:

```
self.YourDate = ko.observable().extend({ date: true });
```

http://momentjs.com/docs/#/displaying/format/