# format a date in a knockout foreach statement

Tags: knockout.js

I am having an issue formatting a date field from a knockout model:

```
<table class="signatures">
    <tbody data-bind="foreach: $root.signatures()">
        <tr>
            <td><span data-bind="text: DateSigned"></span></td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

This is the result that I get:

```
/Date(-62135571600000)/
```

Comment: AFAIK, there's nothing "built in". You'll might have to use a 3rd party Javascrript library like **moment.js**. See here for an example: http://stackoverflow.com/a/17456175/325521

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you have is a Javascript Date which is just the milliseconds from January 1st 1970.  You need to create a formatter that will format the javascript date into something more readable to the user.

Depending if you are using UTC dates you will need to check the local of the user before formatting or just let the user know which timezone your dates are in.

Here is a [MDN article](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date) on all the functions that javascript inherently has that you can perform on your date object.

So, I would create a date function that formats the date for you.

```
function formatDate(odate) {
  var date = ko.util.unwrapObservable(odate);
  var year = date.getYear();
  var month = date.getMonth() + 1;
  var day = date.getDate();
  return year + '/' + month + '/' + day;
}
```

then inside your view you could:

```
<table class="signatures">
    <tbody data-bind="foreach: $root.signatures()">
        <tr>
            <td><span data-bind="text: formatDate(DateSigned)"></span></td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```