# Date comparision on cshtml view

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, razor, knockout.js, knockout-mvc

I am using the below code to compare 2 dates on cshtml view with knockout binding.

```
data-bind="visible: (new Date(appointmentDate) - new Date() < 0) && isStart()"
```

It is working fine but that is including time as well while comparing. I don't want to include time in comparision only date.

Comment: For my knowledge and correct me if I'm wrong. Date is a DateTime with the time set to 00:00:00. 
If in your case appointmentDate have setted a time.
Just do 
New DateTime(appointmentDate).Date

Comment: My bad actually it is knockout.js  binding. Let me update the question with full code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I quick search on google pointed me to [Formatting Date in Knockout Template](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17455784/formatting-date-in-knockout-template) this will allow us to get the date and compare it. Looking like

```
data-bind="visible: (
    moment(new Date(appointmentDate)).format('MM/DD/YYYY') - 
    moment(new Date()) < 0) && isStart()"
```

I didn't try just let me know if works

Also momento allows you to calculate difference of dates

```
var dateB = moment('2014-11-11');
var dateC = moment('2014-10-11');

console.log('Difference is ', dateB.diff(dateC), 'milliseconds');
console.log('Difference is ', dateB.diff(dateC, 'days'), 'days');
console.log('Difference is ', dateB.diff(dateC, 'months'), 'months');
```

So basically we would do

```
data-bind="visible: (
        moment(new Date(appointmentDate)).format('MM/DD/YYYY').diff(new Date().format('MM/DD/YYYY'),'days') < 0) && isStart()"
```

Comment: Formating is working with this but I guess subtraction is not working after putting moment.

Comment: correct with moment need to use diff. Thanks for your help.

Comment: (moment(new Date(appointmentDate)).diff( moment(new Date()),'days') <= 0) && isStart()