# Changing date format from dd/mm/yyyy to yyyy-mm-dd in knockout.js

Tags: javascript, knockout.js, webforms

I have no experience of using knockout.js.  I've inherited a booking form which uses a mixture of knockout and C# ASP.NET. We recently upgraded the database to the latest version of MySQL, which is a lot more particular about the format in which the date is entered than the older version.  In most cases I've been able to get around this by tweaking either C# or SQL, but in one part of the form I haven't found a solution.  The dates are prepopulated in the form input in dd/mm/yyyy format.  I want to change this to yyyy-mm-dd so that I can use date inputs rather than text inputs

There are two form inputs which look like this

```
<input type="text" size="10" maxlength="10" class="normaltext" data-bind="attr:{id:'returnDate-'+Id},value:FlightInfo.ReturnDate, enable:$root.FlightsAdvanced() == 'true' && !FlightInfo.OwnFlight()">
```

The other one, obviously, is for the departure date.  They appear to be populated from the following function in a javascript file.

```
function FlightInfo(depDate, retDate) {

 this.OwnFlight = ko.observable(false);
 this.FirstCode = ko.observable("");
 this.SecondCode = ko.observable("");
 this.DepartureDate = ko.observable(depDate);
 this.ReturnDate = ko.observable(retDate);
 this.ReqTransferIn = ko.observable(0);
 this.ReqTransferOut = ko.observable(0);
}
```

If I replace `ko.observable(retDate)` with a hard coded date, eg 2020-09-09, and submit the form then it works, however if I hard code the same date directly into the text input in place of `value:FlightInfo.ReturnDate` then it doesn't - the form takes the date in the wrong format from knockout and an error is thrown.

I've tried using moment.js as suggested in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17455784/formatting-date-in-knockout-template), but it didn't work for me.  How can I reformat `depDate` and `retDate` as yyyy-mm-dd

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I eventually solved this in the C# layer by changing a few instances of `.ToShortDateString()` to `.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd")`.

Answer (score -1):

Using moment.js is the right way to achieve this, when creating flightInfo, two observables should be modified like this:

```
 this.DepartureDate = ko.observable(moment(depDate).format('YYYY-MM-DD'));
 this.ReturnDate = ko.observable(moment(retDate).format('YYYY-MM-DD'));
```

if these changes do not reflect in your text input, than you should debug if you have moment.js included and activated in proper manner.

Comment: That's the exact code I've tried and it breaks my form.  The version of knockout is quite old I think - 2.1.0.  I'll try a more recent version and see what happens.